# Remote desktop connection to kvm virtual machine starts working after vnc-logon?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, remote-desktop, vnc, debian-jessie

I am running a Windows XP on kvm inside my debian system. Everything runs smoothly and I can connect via VNC as well as via Remote Desktop.

VNC connection is naturally supported right from boot up and always works for me. For Remote Desktop I have to wait until the Windows service is started until I can logon.

Sometimes, however, Remote Desktop seems to not start at all: Regardless of how long I wait, I cannot logon via Remote Desktop connection. But if I then logon via VNC, also Remote Desktop **always** works instantaneously.

I really wonder why this is the case. Might this come from any misconfiguration?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VNC connection you speak of is not a service in the guest, it's a console connection to the hypervisor, and has nothing to do with whether the guest OS is up or not.

RDP depends on the guest OS (Windows) services to be up and running, especially networking. I suspect what happens is your Windows guest doesn't bring up some parts of it's network stack until you connect via a console and login, at which point, since the stack RDP depends on is up and running, it (RDP) will also work.

I vaguely recall desktop Windows editions (2000 and XP especially) failing to bring up the NIC before everything else, thus failing automated logons, but it's been a very long while since I've run into this issue